# convex conjugate $f^*$ is proper if both $f$ and $f^{**}$ are

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $f$ and $f^{**}$ on $\mathbb R^d$ are proper functions where 
$f^*$ stands for the convex conjugate of $f$ why does that follow that $f^*$ is proper, too?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could argue by contradiction. Assume that $f^*$ is not proper. Then it is either (1) equal to the constant $+\infty$ function or (2) it attains the value $-\infty$ somewhere (say, at $y_0$).

Now look at the definition of $f^{**}$:

$$ f^{**}(x) = \sup_{y \in \mathbb R^d} [(x,y) - f^*(y)]$$

Can you see what consequences (1) and (2) have for properness of $f^{**}$, respectively?

Comment: (2) is still ok?? negative infinity somewhere for f* means positive infinity for f** somewhere so it is ok???

Comment: In case of (2), you have $f^{**}(x) \ge (x,y_0) - f^*(y_0) = +\infty $ for every $x$.